# Meteor Pub/sub does not work when I access the application from a public link (react-router) or when I reload it

Tags: mongodb, meteor, react-router, meteor-react, meteor-publications

I have a public link on my react-router V5.

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/colaborativo/:id" component={Colaborativo}/>

      <PrivateRoute>
...
```

When I access the link through a button, the application works correctly: Retrieves the parameter from the url, subscribes to the collection and retrieves the document. As this is a public link, I need it to be accessible directly from the link, without going through a previous screen or pressing a button.
But when **I reload the page** with the F5 key, or when I try to access from another tab **through the link**, the application does not work, as the Meteor synchronization does not happen and the props remain undefined. I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
```

this is the portion of the code that makes the pub/sub:

```
export default withTracker(
  () => {   
    let { id } = useParams();  

  console.log(id)

    const handles = [
      Meteor.subscribe(
        "experienciaOne",
        id
      )
    ];

    const loading = handles.some(handle => !handle.ready());
    

      
      var laExp = Experiencias.findOne(id)      
      console.log(laExp)
    

    return {
      isLoading: loading,
      Experiencia: laExp
    };
  }
)(Colaborativo);
```

This is the publication in my publish.js:

```
Meteor.publish("experienciaOne", function(id) {      
  let rta = Experiencias.find({ _id: id });        
  return rta
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing the state by using the properties. Evidently, the state is executed before the sync.